# Let $G\sim\mathrm{Geometric}(p)$, $U\sim \mathrm{Unif}\{1,...,n\}$, and $G, U$ be independent. Determine the conditional probability $Pr(G=U|G \le n)$

Tags: conditional-probability

I am struggling with the following conditional probability problem.

> Let $G \sim \mathrm{Geometric}(p)$, $U \sim \mathrm{Unif} \{1, \ldots ,n\}$, and $G$ & $U$ be independent. Determine the conditional probability $\mathrm{Pr}(G=U \mid G \le n)$.

Using the definition of conditional probability we obtain

$$\mathrm{Pr}(G=U \mid G \le n) = \frac{\mathrm{Pr}(G=U, G \le n)}{Pr(G \le n)}$$

The denominator is easy enough to compute,

$$\mathrm{Pr}(G \le n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}p(1-p)^{i-1}$$

As for the numerator, I believe we have

$$\mathrm{Pr}(G=U, G \le n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(p(1-p)^{i-1} \cdot \frac{1}{n}\right) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}p(1-p)^{i-1},$$

so that the final answer is $\frac{1}{n}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Your result is correct, but whenever you write "I believe", you are obviosly missing some steps to be convinced yourself. So you should be more detailed to show that $$\mathrm{Pr}(G=U, G \le n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(p(1-p)^{i-1} \cdot \frac{1}{n}\right)$$ really holds.
Hint: $\{G \le n\} = \bigcup_{k=1}^n \{G=k\}$